# Proving that such a code doesn't exists.

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

I am struck on this problem from assignment and could think how to obtain a contradiction.

> Question is Show that there is no binary code with parameters $ [ 2^m , 2^m - m, 3] $ for any m $\geq$ 2.

Can someone please tell how to solve it.

Edit -> I am studying 1st course on coding theory and I have no clue on how to approach this problem.

Comment: What results have you got at your disposal? Any other [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) you want to add? Something must come, for otherwise this question will get closed as *Needing details or clarity*. For example, do you know how to use the parity check matrix to prove that the minimum distance is at least three?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen I don't know how it can be solved.. I am sorry but I don't see any way to obtain contradiction. Can you please help.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen I tried using Hamming bound but that doesn't yield anything.